# Run Tkinter GUI on serial read

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I am using tkinter in python 3.6 on a raspberry pi to display a blue square in the middle of a window. At each click the blue square should disappear and reappear after 2 seconds on a different random location.

I need the code to start after the serial port of the raspberry pi reads information from a RFID scanner. The idea is that my cat will go through the door of the box that will contain the pie and a touchscreen, the RFID reads the animal's chip and starts the procedure described above. If no interaction occurs for a whole minute the screen goes back to black and the task starts listening to the serial port again, until the cat eventually comes back and everything starts again.

Here is a simplified version of the code

```
try:
    import Tkinter as TK
except:
    import tkinter as TK

import random as RAN

class THR:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.config(background='black')

        self.screenYpixels = 600
        self.screenXpixels = 1024
        self.ITI = 2000

        self.background = TK.Canvas(root, width=1024, height=600, bg='black',
                                    bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')

        self.background.pack()
        self.newtrial()

    def newtrial(self):
        self.xpos = RAN.randrange(200, 1000)
        self.ypos = RAN.randrange(100, 500)

        self.stimulus = TK.Canvas(root,width=100,height=100,bg='blue', bd=0,
                                  highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
        self.stimulus.place(x=self.xpos, y=self.ypos, anchor="c")
        self.stimulus.bind("<Button-1>", self.response)

        self.exitbutton()

    def response(self, event):
        self.stimulus.place_forget()
        self.intertrialinterval()

    def intertrialinterval(self, *args):
        self.root.after(self.ITI,self.newtrial)

    def exitbutton(self):
        self.exitButton = TK.Button(self.root, bg="green")
        self.exitButton.place(relx=0.99, rely=0.01, anchor="c")
        self.exitButton.bind("<Button-1>", self.exitprogram)

    def exitprogram(self, root):
        self.root.quit()


root = TK.Tk()
THR(root)
root.mainloop()
```

And here there is some code I manage to put together to read the cat's ID from the implanted chip

```
import serial
import struct
import binascii
import os

ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
        baudrate = 19200,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=1
        )
while 1:
    if ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
                i = ser.readline()
                catID = binascii.b2a_hex(i)
                catID = catID[10:20]
                print(catID)
```

How can I properly setup the code to achieve a continuous, stand-alone system that:

1. Detects if the cat crossed the door
2. Starts the task (shows a blue square on the
   screen, etc..) and stops listening to the serial port
3. if 60 seconds have passed without interaction goes
   to black screen
4. Serial port is set again to listen

Comment: I'd suggest you change your serial code so that it is a function. Your tkinter code will call that function periodically to check once if there is any serial data and if there is return the catID. At the moment your code has a while loop in it which won't work with tkinter.

Comment: Thanks very much, that is exactly what I setup in the last few days. As soon as I am sure it works I will put here the code / pseudocode.